# Fetch Pull Request Review Comments of Private Repository of GitHub using API

Tags: github, github-api

I want to fetch the Review Comments of all Pull Requests raised for a GitHub repository. Its an enterprise GitHub and private repository.
For Instance:

- URL of github is https://github.mycomp.com
- URL of Repo is https://github.mycomp.com/MyRepo/MyProject

How can I use GitHub API to fetch all review comments of all PRs raised.

Answer (score 0):

The API has a Pulls end point: https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.17/v3/pulls/

You can get all pulls for a repo using the following curl:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token PERSONALACCESSTOKEN" -get https://GHEURL/api/v3/repos/REPOOWNER/REPO/pulls?state=all
```

So from the example URL this would be

```
curl -H "Authorization: token PERSONALACCESSTOKEN" -get https://github.mycomp.com/api/v3/repos/MyRepo/MyProject/pulls?state=all
```

Once you have the list of Pulls you will need to find the pulls you are interested in, then use the pulls/comments API endpoint to look at the review comments:
https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.17/v3/pulls/comments/

Example CURL:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token PERSONALACCESSTOKEN" -get https://github.mycomp.com/api/v3/repos/MyRepo/MyProject/pulls/3/comments
```

If the comments you are looking for aren't review comments then you would need to use the Issues/Comments API endpoint:
https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.17/v3/issues/comments/

Example CURL:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token PERSONALACCESSTOKEN" -get https://github.mycomp.com/api/v3/repos/MyRepo/MyProject/issues/3/comments
```